What is wrong with my path tracer in Vulkan?
I wonder whether some of you have ever stumbled upon the same problem as I have. I am trying to write a simple path tracer in Vulkan, using only diffuse BRDF for now until everything works as intended. I have written the same path tracer on CPU using embree and I tried to duplicate the code inside my generation and hit shader, yet the result is nowhere near the same.
Images of first bounce direction, normals and accumulated result of path tracer here:
https://imgur.com/a/BDdmq24
I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I'm trying to reproduce the errror with my fully functional CPU raytracer, trying the same code for hemisphere cosine sampling etc to pinpoint the exact line of error and nothing works.
If you're none the wiser as well, I would certainly appreciate any suggestion for debugging or any advice. If there is something to make it easier for you to help me somehow, just say the word and I will oblige.
GPU is GTX1060 6GB, so that shouldn't be a problem, it should just make things slower to my knowledge, as it doesn't have RTX core.
I wholeheartedly appreciate every single second you spend here trying to help me.
// RANDOM.GLSL
// of rounds of the Tiny Encryption Algorithm. See Zafar, Olano, and Curtis,
// "GPU Random Numbers via the Tiny Encryption Algorithm"
uint tea(uint val0, uint val1)
{
  uint v0 = val0;
  uint v1 = val1;
  uint s0 = 0;

  for(uint n = 0; n < 16; n++)
  {
    s0 += 0x9e3779b9;
    v0 += ((v1 << 4) + 0xa341316c) ^ (v1 + s0) ^ ((v1 >> 5) + 0xc8013ea4);
    v1 += ((v0 << 4) + 0xad90777d) ^ (v0 + s0) ^ ((v0 >> 5) + 0x7e95761e);
  }

  return v0;
}

// Generate a random unsigned int in [0, 2^24) given the previous RNG state
// using the Numerical Recipes linear congruential generator
uint lcg(inout uint prev)
{
  uint LCG_A = 1664525u;
  uint LCG_C = 1013904223u;
  prev       = (LCG_A * prev + LCG_C);
  return prev & 0x00FFFFFF;
}

// Generate a random float in [0, 1) given the previous RNG state
float rnd(inout uint prev)
{
  return (float(lcg(prev)) / float(0x01000000));
}



//-----------------------------------------------
//RAYCOMMON.GLSL
struct hitPayload
{
  vec3 rayOrigin;
  vec3 rayDir;
  float cos_term;
  float pdf;
  vec3 brdf;
  bool miss;
  int depth;
  bool hitLight;
  vec3 emission;
};

mat3 getWorldMatrix(vec3 t_normal)
{
    vec3 basis2;
    if(abs(t_normal.y) > abs(t_normal.x))
    {
        basis2 = vec3(t_normal.z, 0.0f, -t_normal.y);
    }
    else
    {
        basis2 = vec3(-t_normal.z, t_normal.x, 0.0f);
    }
    basis2 = normalize(basis2);
    vec3 basis1 = normalize(cross(basis2, t_normal));

    mat3 out_mat = mat3(basis1, basis2, t_normal);
    return out_mat;
}



// -------------------------------------------------
// RAYTRACER.RGEN
#version 460
#extension GL_EXT_ray_tracing : require
#extension GL_GOOGLE_include_directive : enable
#extension GL_EXT_shader_explicit_arithmetic_types_int64 : require


#include "raycommon.glsl"
#include "random.glsl"

// clang-format off
layout(location = 0) rayPayloadEXT hitPayload prd;

layout(set = 0, binding = 0) uniform accelerationStructureEXT topLevelAS;
layout(set = 0, binding = 1, rgba32f) uniform image2D image;

layout(set = 1, binding = 0) uniform UniformBufferObject {
        mat4 viewProj;     // Camera view * projection
        mat4 viewInverse;  // Camera inverse view matrix
        mat4 projInverse; 
} ubo;

layout(push_constant) uniform _PushConstantRay
{
  vec4  clearColor;
  vec3  lightPosition;
  float lightIntensity;
  int   lightType;
  int   frame;
} pcRay;
// clang-format on

const int NB_SAMPLES = 1;

void main()
{
    uint seed = tea(gl_LaunchIDEXT.y * gl_LaunchSizeEXT.x + gl_LaunchIDEXT.x, pcRay.frame);
    float r1 = rnd(seed);
    float r2 = rnd(seed);

    vec2 subpixel_jitter = vec2(r1, r2);

    vec3 color = vec3(0);

    for(int smpl = 0; smpl < NB_SAMPLES; smpl++)
    {
            // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // gl_LaunchIDEXT contains the integer coordinates of the pixel being rendered
        // gl_LaunchSizeEXT then corresponds to the image size provided
        const vec2 pixelCenter = vec2(gl_LaunchIDEXT.xy);
        const vec2 inUV        = pixelCenter / vec2(gl_LaunchSizeEXT.xy);
        vec2       d           = inUV * 2.0 - 1.0;

        vec4 origin    = ubo.viewInverse * vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
        vec4 target    = ubo.projInverse * vec4(d.x, d.y, 1, 1);
        vec4 direction = ubo.viewInverse * vec4(normalize(target.xyz), 0);

        uint  rayFlags = gl_RayFlagsOpaqueEXT;
        float tMin     = 0.001;
        float tMax     = 10000.0;

        prd.rayOrigin = origin.xyz;
        prd.rayDir = direction.xyz;
        prd.cos_term = 0;
        prd.pdf = 0;
        prd.brdf = vec3(0);
        prd.miss = false;
        prd.depth = 0;
        prd.hitLight = false;
        prd.emission = vec3(0);

        vec3 hitValues = vec3(0);
        vec3 weights = vec3(1.0);

        for(;prd.depth < 16; prd.depth++)
        {
            traceRayEXT(topLevelAS,     // acceleration structure
                        rayFlags,       // rayFlags
                        0xFF,           // cullMask
                        0,              // sbtRecordOffset
                        0,              // sbtRecordStride
                        0,              // missIndex
                        prd.rayOrigin.xyz,     // ray origin
                        tMin,           // ray min range
                        prd.rayDir.xyz,  // ray direction
                        tMax,           // ray max range
                        0               // payload (location = 0)
            );

            if(prd.miss == true)
            {
                hitValues = pcRay.clearColor.xyz * 0.8;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if(prd.hitLight)
                {
                    hitValues = hitValues + (prd.emission * weights);
                    prd.hitLight = false;
                }
                weights = weights * (prd.brdf * max(0.0, prd.cos_term) / prd.pdf);
            }

        }
        color = color + hitValues;
    }

    if(pcRay.frame > 0)
    {
        float a         = 1.0f / float(pcRay.frame + 1);
        vec3 prevColor  = imageLoad(image, ivec2(gl_LaunchIDEXT.xy)).xyz;
        imageStore(image, ivec2(gl_LaunchIDEXT.xy), vec4(mix(prevColor, color/NB_SAMPLES, a), 1.f));
    }
    else
    {
        imageStore(image, ivec2(gl_LaunchIDEXT.xy), vec4(color/NB_SAMPLES, 1.0));
    }
}



// ------------------------------------------------------------
// RAYTRACER.RCHIT
#version 460
#extension GL_EXT_ray_tracing : require
#extension GL_EXT_nonuniform_qualifier : enable
#extension GL_EXT_scalar_block_layout : enable
#extension GL_GOOGLE_include_directive : enable

#extension GL_EXT_shader_explicit_arithmetic_types_int64 : require
#extension GL_EXT_buffer_reference2 : require

#include "raycommon.glsl"
#include "random.glsl"

hitAttributeEXT vec2 attribs;

struct Vertex  // See ObjLoader, copy of VertexObj, could be compressed for device
{
    vec3 pos;
    vec3 nrm;
    vec3 color;
    vec2 texCoord;
};

struct WaveFrontMaterial  // See ObjLoader, copy of MaterialObj, could be compressed for device
{
    vec3  ambient;
    vec3  diffuse;
    vec3  specular;
    vec3  transmittance;
    vec3  emission;
    float shininess;
    float ior;       // index of refraction
    float dissolve;  // 1 == opaque; 0 == fully transparent
    int   illum;     // illumination model (see http://www.fileformat.info/format/material/)
    int   textureId;
};

struct ObjDesc
{
    int      txtOffset;             // Texture index offset in the array of textures
    uint64_t vertexAddress;         // Address of the Vertex buffer
    uint64_t indexAddress;          // Address of the index buffer
    uint64_t materialAddress;       // Address of the material buffer
    uint64_t materialIndexAddress;  // Address of the triangle material index buffer
};

// clang-format off
layout(location = 0) rayPayloadInEXT hitPayload prd;

layout(buffer_reference, scalar) buffer Vertices {Vertex v[]; }; // Positions of an object
layout(buffer_reference, scalar) buffer Indices {ivec3 i[]; }; // Triangle indices
layout(buffer_reference, scalar) buffer Materials {WaveFrontMaterial m[]; }; // Array of all materials on an object
layout(buffer_reference, scalar) buffer MatIndices {int i[]; }; // Material ID for each triangle
layout(set = 0, binding = 0) uniform accelerationStructureEXT topLevelAS;
layout(set = 1, binding = 1, scalar) buffer ObjDesc_ { ObjDesc i[]; } objDesc;

layout(push_constant) uniform _PushConstantRay
{
    vec4  clearColor;
    vec3  lightPosition;
    float lightIntensity;
    int   lightType;
    int   frame;
} pcRay;


const float M_PI   = 3.14159265358979323846;
const float M_1_PI = 0.318309886183790671538;

void main()
{
    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    // Acquisition of all needed information from buffers
    // ObjDesc holds addresses for vertex buffer, index buffer, materials etc
    //
    // MatIndices holds material ID for each triangle
    //
    // Materials is an array of all materials
    //
    // Indices is for triangle Indices
    //
    // And Vertices goes for the vertices themselves
    ObjDesc    objResource = objDesc.i[gl_InstanceCustomIndexEXT];
    MatIndices matIndices  = MatIndices(objResource.materialIndexAddress);
    Materials  materials   = Materials(objResource.materialAddress);
    Indices    indices     = Indices(objResource.indexAddress);
    Vertices   vertices    = Vertices(objResource.vertexAddress);

    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    // We query materials of currently hit triangle
    int               matIdx = matIndices.i[gl_PrimitiveID];
    WaveFrontMaterial mat    = materials.m[matIdx];


    ivec3 ind = indices.i[gl_PrimitiveID];

    // Vertex of the triangle
    Vertex v0 = vertices.v[ind.x];
    Vertex v1 = vertices.v[ind.y];
    Vertex v2 = vertices.v[ind.z];

    const vec3 barycentrics = vec3(1.0 - attribs.x - attribs.y, attribs.x, attribs.y);

    // Computing the coordinates of the hit position
    const vec3 pos      = v0.pos * barycentrics.x + v1.pos * barycentrics.y + v2.pos * barycentrics.z;
    const vec3 worldPos = vec3(gl_ObjectToWorldEXT * vec4(pos, 1.0));  // Transforming the position to world space

    // Computing the normal at hit position
    const vec3 nrm      = normalize(v0.nrm * barycentrics.x + v1.nrm * barycentrics.y + v2.nrm * barycentrics.z);
     vec3 worldNrm = normalize(vec3(nrm * gl_WorldToObjectEXT));  // Transforming the normal to world space

    float check = dot(worldNrm, -prd.rayDir);
    if(check < 0.0)
    {
    worldNrm = -worldNrm;
    }

    if(mat.illum == 100)
    {
        prd.hitLight = true;
        prd.emission = mat.emission;
    }


    // rho for russian roulette
    //prd.rho = max(mat.diffuse.x, max(mat.diffuse.y, mat.diffuse.z));

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // hemisphere cosine sampling of diffuse material
    uint seed = tea(gl_LaunchIDEXT.y * gl_LaunchSizeEXT.x + gl_LaunchIDEXT.x, pcRay.frame);
    float ksi1 = rnd(seed);
    float ksi2 = rnd(seed);
    float trig_temp = 2.0f * M_PI * ksi1;
    float sqrt_temp = sqrt(1.0f - ksi2);

    vec3 t_out_dir = vec3(cos(trig_temp) * sqrt_temp, sin(trig_temp) * sqrt_temp, sqrt(ksi2));
    t_out_dir = normalize(getWorldMatrix(worldNrm) * t_out_dir);

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    prd.rayOrigin = worldPos;
    prd.rayDir = t_out_dir;
    prd.cos_term = max(0.0, dot(t_out_dir, worldNrm));
    prd.pdf = prd.cos_term * M_1_PI;
    prd.brdf = mat.diffuse / M_PI;
}


The link to your shader code gives a 404 Not found. Please include the relevant parts in your post.

It's done, sorry for the inconvenience
